# Gitlab CI how to deploy PHP?

Tags: php, deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I use gitlab, gitab-ci and I'm quite new to Continuous Integration. I try to test and deploy over bash script on code pushes.

that's how my .gitlab-ci.yml looks like where on deploy I try to change user but will not work

```
before_script:
  - composer install --prefer-dist > /dev/null

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy


unitTesting:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Running PHPUnit Tests"
    - php vendor/bin/phpunit --colors --debug  --coverage-text

job_deploy_master:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - /bin/su - myuser -c "deploy.sh" //here I try to change linux user to be able to checkout code but fails with  **su: must be run from a terminal**
  tags:
    - php
```

and here I have the bash which supposed to pull codes on production site if tests are passing

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting Deploy"
printf '%s\n' "${SUDO_USER:-$USER}" //I'm interested to see which user try to run this script outputs gitlab-runner
cd /home/builds/gpx-convertor
git pull
composer install --prefer-dist > /dev/null
```

I was trying to google to find some examples related to php but without success. Can somebody show how does should work

Comment: I'm afraid it's rather unclear what is the problem. You have the process logically defined so is any of the stages failing? My advice is not to concentrate on somebody else's samples but on your own case - define what you want to achieve and what would be the ideal process for you. Then try to setup that process and post here a particular problem that you might stumble upon.

Comment: let me comment my examples where do they fail and maybe is going to be more clear my problem

Comment: OK, now it's clearer so let's concentrate on your deployment process: I don't think you can change the user (I might be wrong) and you probably shouldn't anyway. Also you probably don't need to do `git pull` because you already have the code checked out. What are the actions that you want to perform during the deployment?

Comment: get the latest commit what passed the tests in a given directory, run composer to update dependencies. In this case gitlab and production server are on the same server. Gitlab is under `/home/git/gitlab` and I would like to deploy the code in `/home/builds/my-project`

Comment: The code on which your unit tests were performed is the same code that you have already available in your deploy stage (all the `script` commands are run inside the project directory containing code version for which the build process runs) so you don't need to pull it again. Also, `composer install` in your `before_script` is run before every stage, including the deployment one, so you don't need to run it in your Bash script.

Comment: So, I think you should do `bash deploy.sh` instead of `/bin/su` and copy the code of the directory itself (`.`) - see my previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564681/gitlab-ci-how-to-deploy-the-latest-to-a-specific-directory). You should only need to properly set permissions so that *gitlab-runner* can perform those file operations.

Comment: cool I will do like that thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing su -c with sudo -Hu