# How to deploy a gitlab project to a specific directory on the server?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a project in gitlab and want to deploy this to a specific directory on a Linux server using the .gitlab-ci.yml for which I am facing an issue.
I have setup a gitlab runner for "cms-project" and added .gitlab-ci.yml to the root directory
When I push to the repository, the runner fetches the commits to the following directory

```
home/gitlab-runner/builds/ziwwUK3Jz/0/project/cms_project
```

Now I want the runner to fetch the commit to the dev server which is located in

```
/var/www/project-cms.com/html
```

I have tried the changes and below is the .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
job_main:
   type: deploy
   script: cd /var/www/project-cms.com/html && git pull

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  variables:
    BRANCH: master
  script:
    - composer install
```

but I am getting the following error

```
Removing modules/contrib/
Removing vendor/
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ cd /var/www/project-cms.com/html && git pull
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

The user has the root permissions to the directory.
I have already gone through this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564681/gitlab-ci-how-to-deploy-the-latest-to-a-specific-directory" but that did not help

can anyone please help me to deploy the project to the "/var/www/project-cms.com/html" directory?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you did not understand the difference between the gitlab-runner and your server

This code is running inside a "machine" called gitlab runner that is responsible to execute anything that you want. But it is not your web server.

To be able to deploy your code, you need to build a script that will run inside this runner and you need to understand that your entire code is inside this runner (this is the reason that you found your code inside the `/builds` folder.

So you need to tell to your runner to copy your code to your webserver, using any protocol/binary like ssh, ftp, sftp etc.

Edit: If your runner is running inside your webserver, you just need to copy the code to your folder, do not need to pull with git anymore

Some examples here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/

Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/

Runner docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/